# How to get IntelliJ IDEA to `activator publishLocal` as a task?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get IntelliJ IDEA to run `activator publishLocal` as a task, so that it publishes updated artifacts to the local repository for use by other projects.

If there is a better way to share code between projects without publishing, that would work as well.

You can create an SBT Task in the "Run" section of IntelliJ IDEA, but you can't create an "Activator" task, nor does it seem like you can just run any command-line script.

Comment: I think that [activator has been EOL'd](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator), so I would recommend using SBT for this.

Comment: Have you tried to configure it as an `External Tool`? 'Preferences->Tools->External Tools'

Answer (score 0):

[Activator has been decomissioned](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator), and any support removed from the IntelliJ Scala plugin as of version 2017.3

However, activator was based on sbt, thus the `publishLocal` task works just as well when run as an sbt task.

You can run a command line script with a Bash run configuration, for instance.